# raspberry TTL printer USB not able to connect

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, usb, thermal-printer

I was following these [installation instruction](https://learn.adafruit.com/networked-thermal-printer-using-cups-and-raspberry-pi/connect-and-configure-printer) about configuring a TTL Thremal printer in USB.

Thus when I try : `echo -e "This is a test.\\n\\n\\n" > /dev/ttyUSB0` it gives me a `bash: no permission`.
I tried using sudo mode : it gaves me the same result

Any idea why ?

Thanks in advance

[edit]

[Posted on Raspberry Pie StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/124280/using-ttl-thermal-printer-usb)

Answer (score 1):

Use

`echo -e "This is a test.\\n\\n\\n" > /dev/usb/lp0`

you also must do: `sudo gpasswd -a <YOUR USERNAME> lp`

instead of

`echo -e "This is a test.\\n\\n\\n" > /dev/ttyUSB0`

This took hours for me to figure out, full credit to this guide: https://www.theamplituhedron.com/articles/How-to-use-a-tiny-thermal-printer-with-Raspberry-Pi/